# How can I interrupt a thread running JDBC query with Postgresql?

Tags: java, multithreading, postgresql, jdbc

I have a thread pool running tasks that mostly query Postgresql using JDBC. It would be convenient if cancelling a future for a submitted task would cancel any query in progress. Is there an easy way to do this? It only has to work for Postgresql.

Comment: Your runable needs to check for `Thread.interrupted()`, that way if you try and cancel the future, the future can react to that and cancel the statements it is executing

Comment: The problem is that the thread is inside Postgres JDBC driver code when it gets interrupted, specifically reading from a socket and nothing happens.

Comment: if that process doesn't react to it there is not too much you can do. I believe you should be able to have some sort of timeout + rollback logic there in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Statement.cancel()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#cancel--):

> Cancels this Statement object if both the DBMS and driver support aborting an SQL statement. This method can be used by one thread to cancel a statement that is being executed by another thread.

`cancel()` is implemented in the PostgreSQL JDBC Driver (s. [PgStatement](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/jdbc/PgStatement.java))

Comment: The problem with that approach is that I would need to have access to the statement(s) being used by the task. This is possible but messy.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the Postgres JDBC connection has a non-standard cancelQuery() method that cancels whatever query is running on the connection. So I wrap the future returned when submitting the task and its connection together and override cancel() to call cancelQuery().

```
import org.postgresql.core.BaseConnection;

private static class ConFuture<T> implements Future<T> {

    private Future<T> wrapped;
    private volatile Connection con;

    public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
        boolean ans = wrapped.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
        Connection con = this.con;
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.unwrap(BaseConnection.class).cancelQuery();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                log.error("Unable to cancel query: " + e);
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: You'd better file an enhancement request as `BaseConnection` interface is supposed to be driver-internal. Public extensions are defined in `org.postgresql.PGConnection`